# Is it better to store array in a variable or directly pass an array to a function inside a loop?

Tags: php

Which of the 2 ways of passing array to a function inside a loop is recommended?

Are there any performance difference between them?

**First method:**

```
<?php  

foreach ($variable as $val) {
    $array = array(
            'one'   => $val->prop1,
            'two'   => $val->prop2,
        );

    some_function( $array );
}

?>
```

**Second Method**

```
<?php

foreach ($variable as $val) {
    some_function( array(
            'one'   => $val->prop1,
            'two'   => $val->prop2,
        ));
}

?>
```

Comment: There are benchmarking sites that can tell you which is faster. Try running it on `eval.in`

Comment: what do you want to do? Can't you pass the $variable to the function directly and do the loop inside the function. If you really need to do it then both are ok.

Comment: In the first example your create a new variable in a memory. 
Better to use the second example.

Comment: Is there any good reason you don't pass `$val` to `some_function()` as argument?

Comment: Better doesn't necessarily mean faster.... which one is more readable?

Comment: @jonju, no I cannot pass $val to the function.
@axiac, `some_function()` is a built-in function that cannot accept $val

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first example you provided would have one more `opcode` than the second example, that is the `ASSIGN` opcode.

Though the performance difference between the two would be negligible, the second example would be a *tiny* bit faster than the first one, which you needn't need to worry about anyway.

And as you know,

> Premature optimization is the root of all evil